# How to delete a file (deep) in a ZIP folder in Python?

Tags: json, io, zip, python-2.6

I'm writing a script that is extracting 2 JSON files from deep (3 folders down) in a ZIP Folder, modifying its contents, and writing those files back into that same folder. The only issue is that when I write the JSON Files back into the folder where they were initially pulled from, they do not overwrite so now I have 4 files named (product, product, package, package). I wish to delete or overwrite the non-modified files but don't know how.

I have looked up how to do it on other threads and it says it's not supported but I was hoping by now someone had addressed this without having to do the "rewrite the entire directory minus the old files into a new ZIP" routine. I've also tried writing to the zip file with 'w' mode but that just deletes the whole other contents of the zip file.

This is how I'm writing each file back into the ZIP file

`zf = zipfile.ZipFile(ZipName, 'a')`

`zf.write('package.json',addressBook[0],compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED`

`zf.write('product.json',addressBook[1],compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED`

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that update or delete functionality isn't implemented in *zipfile*, so you'll have to do it yourself. Did you try https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr?